# How to detect if the image taken is selfie using image processing

Tags: image, image-processing, face-detection

I am doing a project,where I need to determine if the image is self taken or not? I am confused whether to use machine learning approach or image processing ? Machine learning approach may not give me very effective results.I am looking for image processing method.Can anyone help me out here..?? I can detect the faces in the image but that is not enough.

Comment: Obligatory XKCD reference: [https://xkcd.com/1425](https://xkcd.com/1425/)

Answer (score 0):

Machine learning will work way better in my opinion. With few exemples you should get a correct result. But it won't be perfect.

If you want something more occurate you will need other detailed. For exemple if it is a smartphone application you know if the front camera was used. Maybe another great source of data is the accelerometer because selfies are not taken the same way of regular picture.

If you have faces in the picture and another relevant indicator you probably can state that the picture is a selfie.